# How to get a word under cursor in Livecode

Tags: livecode

how to get a word under cursor in Livecode. Now i am using following code but it's now working. it's working after I selecting the text.

```
 put the selectedText of field "MytextField" into Ftext
```

eg(small big happy) here 3 words if cursor is in small then it assign to Ftext is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "the mouseChunk" function. In the field script:

```
 on mousemove
put the value of the mouseChunk
end mousemove
```

Should be just the ticket.

Craig Newman

Comment: please give a example\

Answer (score 2):

The `mouseText` function will return the actual text beneath the mouse pointer.

```
on mouseMove
   put the mouseText into fText
   --> fText will contain the word pointed to; e.g. "big"
end mouseMove
```

The `mouseChunk` function returns a chunk description:

```
on mouseMove
   put the mouseChunk into fText
   --> fText will contain something like "char 7 to 9 of field 1"
end mouseMove
```

If you want the text beneath the mouse pointer only when you click, use `the clickWord` or `the clickChunk` properties in a `mouseUp` handler.

Comment: Thank you Devin and dunbarx - the supplemental answers were just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Devin's solution is fine and compact. But try the "mouseChunk" without the "value":

```
put the mouseChunk
```

It gives more information, especially about the field that you are in.

Craig